# Unable to add multiple regex patterns into array list

Tags: java, arrays, regex, arraylist, regex-group

My aim is given a string when a pattern is found, it will then add them into separate arrays.

For example

My test string is

`String input = "this is a sentence continents=Asia end continents=Europe end continents=Africa end continents=Australia end continents=South America end continents=North America end continents=Antartica end";`

The result is

`[continents, Asia, continents, Europe, continents, Africa, continents, Australia, continents, South America, continents, North America]`

What I want is to add them into separate arrays as seen below

`[continents, Asia], [continents, Europe], [continents, Africa], [continents, Australia], [continents, South America], [continents, North America], [continents, Antartica]`

Below are my codes:

```
list = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("continents=(.+?) end ");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) { 
    list.add("continents");
    value = matcher.group(1);
    list.add(value);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're nearly there. You only have to add each match to a different list, and add the list to the outer list:

```
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("continents=(.+?) end ");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) { 
        List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
        innerList.add("continents");
        String value = matcher.group(1);
        innerList.add(value);
        list.add(innerList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
String input = "this is a sentence continents=Asia end continents=Europe end continents=Africa end continents=Australia end continents=South America end continents=North America end continents=Antartica end";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(continents)=(.+?) end ");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
List<List<String>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    lst.add(Arrays.asList(matcher.group(1),matcher.group(2))); 
} 
System.out.println(lst); 
// => [[continents, Asia], [continents, Europe], [continents, Africa], [continents, Australia], [continents, South America], [continents, North America]]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/zxjFYo)

The regex has two capturing groups now, `continents` is captured  into Group 1 and the name is captured into Group 2. The result of the match is added with `Arrays.asList(matcher.group(1),matcher.group(2))` to the `List<List<String>>`.

Note that you may also use a regex like `"(continents)=(.+?)\\s+end\\b"` to support any whitespace and `end` as a whole word that may even match at the end of the string or before any non-word char.